# How to mock object inside of static method?

Tags: java, static, mocking

I'm trying to mock static method inside of static method.

I wonder if it is possible **without using any framework**.

Below is what I have tried.

**Goal:**  Mock ImageIO object so that I know what to expect for return value.

```
class Foo {

  public static SomeObject Run(String path) {
     File file = new File(path);
     BufferedImage buff = ImageIO.read(file);

     SomeObject some = new SomeObject(buff);
     return some;
  }
}
```

I first tried using interface and create a wrapper for ImageIO.

```
 interface ImageReader {
     public BufferedImage read(File file);
 }

 class RealReader implements ImageReader {
     @Override
     public BufferedImage read(File file) {
         return ImageIO.read(file);
     }
 }

 class MockReader implements ImageReader {
     @Override
     public BufferedImage read(File file) {
         BufferedImage buff = new BufferedImage(0,0,0);
         //do whatever I like here and return the buff
         return buff;
     }
 }


 class Foo {

      public static SomeObject run(String path) {
         File file = new File(path);

         //ImageIO wrapper             
         ImageReader reader = getImageReader();
         BufferedImage buff = reader.read(file);


         SomeObject some = new SomeObject(buff);
         return some;
      }

      public static getImageReader() {
         return RealReader();
      }
  }
```

And I tried to override static getImageReader() so that I can return MockReader object
which then call mock version of read() method:

```
class MockFoo {
    @Override
    public static getImageReader() {
        return MockReader();
    }
}
```

**This is my test code:**

```
public void TestRun() {

    MockFoo foo = new MockFoo();
    foo.run();

}
```

Then I figured I can't override static method getImageReader()......

Is there a way to achieve my goal?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way is to change the signature of `run`:

```
public static SomeObject run(ImageReader imageReader, String path) {
    // ...
```

Comment: I agree, this is the way I could think of without framework. Thanks for the tip!